# Strange MYSQL/PHP error: inserts with now()+$i as timestamp occasionally inserts 0

Tags: php, mysql, database, innodb

I observed this strange problem. Inserting with `now()` is fine, but when adding a number to `now()` it sometimes inserts 0. It seems random.

This is the query

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO action_data (user_id, value, create_time, site_id) VALUES (807809, 20, now()+$i, 409666)");
```

the table: `ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=164865 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1`

mysql_version

```
+-------------------------+------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                                    |
+-------------------------+------------------------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 1.0.13-11.6                              |
| protocol_version        | 10                                       |
| version                 | 5.1.52-rel11.6-log                       |
| version_comment         | Percona Server (GPL), 11.6, Revision 140 |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                                   |
| version_compile_os      | unknown-linux-gnu                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

I ran it 100 times in a loop and about first 1/3ish of them are inserted with time 0 and rest of them are fine. Anybody have an idea why it's happening?

Comment: When/Where do you initialize `$i`?

Comment: how is the `$i` populated/calculated?

Comment: $i is the for loop index 0-99, i think cHao's answer makes sense, I'll try it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing here...but it seems in a numeric context (like, say, if you add a number to the return value), `NOW()` returns a timestampish-looking number (not a count of seconds!).  Like, today it might return `20120409161530.000000`.  Now...depending on the value of `$i`, it seems this could easily make for an invalid value.  I mean, what if it's `666666`?  You'd end up with `20120409828196.000000`, which makes no sense as a timestamp...and i'm pretty sure that MySQL just turns invalid values to 0.

You may want to consider something like `NOW() + INTERVAL $i SECOND`, and redefine `$i` to be the number of seconds (or minutes, days, even years if you like...just change `SECOND` to whatever you decide on).  Your resulting times are less likely to turn out all messed up.